# Problema com flexbox

Tags: html5, css3, flexbox

Minha intenção inicialmente foi dividir o `header` em 2 para que uma parte ficasse na esquerda e a outra na direita. Em seguida coloquei um `flex-start` e um `flex-end`, mas não deu certo.

Estou tentando aprender *Flexbox* e creio que seja algo simples, mas que não estou conseguindo no momento.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Meu código:

```css
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
html {
    font-size: 62.5%;

}
body {
    font-family: 'Dosis', sans-serif;
    background-color: #363636;
}
.head {
    font-family: 'Staatliches', cursive;
    padding-top: .5rem;
    font-size: 3rem;
    font-weight: 200;
    padding-right: 1rem;
    color: white;
}
.container {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    font-size: 1.5rem;
}
/* as classes das 2 divs*/
.esquerda {
    justify-content: flex-start;
}
.direita {
    justify-content: flex-end;
}
ul {
    display: inline-flex;
    list-style-type: none;
}
li {
    color: white;
    cursor: pointer;
    padding: 1.5rem 3rem;
}
li:hover {
    transition: all .2s ease-out;
    background-color: #454545;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/styles.css">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
        <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Staatliches" rel="stylesheet">
        <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Dosis" rel="stylesheet">

        <title>Manytestsbudda</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <header>
            <div class="container">
                <div class="esquerda">
                    <ul>
                        <h1 class="head">MKY</h1>
                        <li>Home</li>
                        <li>Planos</li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
                <div  class="direita">
                    <ul>
                        <li>Contato</li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </header>
    </body>
</html>
```

> Réplica do código disponível no [CodePen.io](https://codepen.io/utamo/pen/xmarwJ).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Não funcionou porque `justify-content` é uma propriedade para vc usar em um `flex container`, é uma propriedade que se usa no *container* pai e não diretamente nos elementos filhos dentro do *container* como vc fez.

Aqui entramos em uma das partes mais obscuras do `display:flex`... Vc pode pensar... "a então vou usar o `justify-self` para alinha individualmente cada filho do container. Mas isso também não vai funcionar. Pois `justify-self` só se aplica no `display:grid`, não no `display:flex`. Diferente do `align-self`, que funciona nos dois! Vc pode ler mais sobre isso na documentação oficial W3C: https://www.w3.org/TR/css-align-3/#justify-self-property

Então a solução para alinha um de cada lado é usando `margin`. Isso mesmo `margin-left: auto;` no segundo filho vai fazer com que ele de uma margem que ocupa todo o espaço disponível a sua esquerda, isso vai "prega-lo" na direita. Simples assim...

```css
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
html {
    font-size: 62.5%;

}
body {
    font-family: 'Dosis', sans-serif;
    background-color: #363636;
}
.head {
    font-family: 'Staatliches', cursive;
    padding-top: .5rem;
    font-size: 3rem;
    font-weight: 200;
    padding-right: 1rem;
    color: white;
}
.container {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    font-size: 1.5rem;
}
/* as classes das 2 divs*/
.esquerda {
    /* justify-content: flex-start; */
}
.direita {
    /* justify-content: flex-end; */
    margin-left: auto;
}
ul {
    display: inline-flex;
    list-style-type: none;
}
li {
    color: white;
    cursor: pointer;
    padding: 1.5rem 3rem;
}
li:hover {
    transition: all .2s ease-out;
    background-color: #454545;
}
```

```html
<header>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="esquerda">
            <ul>
                <h1 class="head">MKY</h1>
                <li>Home</li>
                <li>Planos</li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <div  class="direita">
            <ul>
                <li>Contato</li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</header>
```

Answer (score 1):

Veja se é disso que precisa:

```css
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
html {
    font-size: 62.5%;

}
body {
    font-family: 'Dosis', sans-serif;
    background-color: #363636;
}
.head {
    font-family: 'Staatliches', cursive;
    padding-top: .5rem;
    font-size: 3rem;
    font-weight: 200;
    padding-right: 1rem;
    color: white;
}
.container {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    justify-content: space-between;
    font-size: 1.5rem;
}
ul {
    display: inline-flex;
    list-style-type: none;
}
li {
    color: white;
    cursor: pointer;
    padding: 1.5rem 3rem;
}
li:hover {
    transition: all .2s ease-out;
    background-color: #454545;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/styles.css">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
        <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Staatliches" rel="stylesheet">
        <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Dosis" rel="stylesheet">

        <title>Manytestsbudda</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <header>
            <div class="container">
                <div class="esquerda">
                    <ul>
                        <h1 class="head">MKY</h1>
                        <li>Home</li>
                        <li>Planos</li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
                <div  class="direita">
                    <ul>
                        <li>Contato</li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </header>
    </body>
</html>
```

Adicionei o estilo `justify-content: space-between;` no `.container` e tirei os estilos das classes `.esquerda` e `.direita`, que não são necessários e estavam sendo usados erroneamente.

> "*- Estou tentando aprender Flexbox*".

Posso te sugerir um excelente artigo. Com ilustrações que facilitam bastante quando está *codando* um *Flexbox*:

> [CSS-Tricks - A Complete Guide to Flexbox](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/) (em inglês, mas de fácil compreensão).

Comment: Funciona para 2 itens, caso sejam 3 um fina centralizado no meio... Vou dar uma dica de como colocar uma pra cada lado sem o justify

Comment: @hugocsl fiz baseando-me no código postado. O próprio perguntante já separou dois pra um lado (dentro da mesma div) e um pro outro (pra div). Mas sua resposta é sempre bem - vinda! Te considero o mestre do front-end! Kkkk

Comment: Rss, mestre estou longe disso, ainda mais falando de front-end... Mas de CSS eu entendo um pouquinho :D. Eu falei do caso de 3 itens pq já sofri tentando entender pq o justfy-self não funciona e o align-self funciona... Mas os detalhes deixei na resposta.

Comment: Valeu manos! ajudaram mt :)